# i have two drop down menus,if change the value of drop down one it will affect to another drop down

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

**i have two drop down menus,if change the value of drop down one it will affect to another drop down(automatically change the value of drop down two) how to resolve this problem.**

```
  <!--5 pannel starts-->
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Country</div>
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis" id="ccountry"><?php
                                                    if (isset($s_country)) {
                                                        echo $s_country;
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </div>

                                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5"> 
                                                    <div class="profile-edit col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 aj-textfive"> 
                                                        <?php if (empty($s_country[0]) || empty($s_country)): ?> 
                                                            Add 
                                                        <?php else: ?> 
                                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit 
                                                        <?php endif; ?> 
                                                    </div> 
                                                </a> 

                                            </div>
                                            <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                                                            <label class="col-md-4">Country</label> 
                                                            <div class="col-md-8">





                                                                <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control"  
                                                                       value="<?= (isset($s_country)) ? $s_country : null; ?>"><br> 
                                                                    <option value="india">india</option>
                                                                    <option value="aus">aus</option>

                                                                </select>



                                                                <input type="hidden" name="save_country" id="save_country" value="<?= (empty($s_country[0]) || empty($s_country)) ? 'Save' : 'Update'; ?>"> 
                                                                <?php if (empty($s_country[0]) || empty($s_country)): ?> 
                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btnfive" data-target="#collapse5" data-toggle="collapse">Save</button> 
                                                                <?php else: ?> 
                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btnfive" data-target="#collapse5" data-toggle="collapse">Update</button> 
                                                                <?php endif; ?> 
                                                                <button type="button" data-target="#collapse5" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button> 
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--5 pannel ends-->

                                        <!--6 pannel starts-->
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">State</div>
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis" id="cstate"><?php
                                                    if (isset($s_state)) {
                                                        echo $s_state;
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6"> 
                                                    <div class="profile-edit col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 aj-textsix"> 
                                                        <?php if (empty($s_state[0]) || empty($s_state)): ?> 
                                                            Add 
                                                        <?php else: ?> 
                                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit 
                                                        <?php endif; ?> 
                                                    </div> 
                                                </a> 

                                            </div>
                                            <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <div class="row">

                                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                                                            <label class="col-md-4">State</label> 
                                                            <div class="col-md-8">

                                                                 <select name="state" id="state" type ="text" class="form-control"  
                                                                       value="<?= (isset($s_state)) ? $s_state : null; ?>"><br> 
                                                                    <option value="indiaa">indiaa</option>
                                                                    <option value="aussss">aussss</option>

                                                                </select>



                                                                <input type="hidden" name="save_state" id="save_state" value="<?= (empty($s_state[0]) || empty($s_state)) ? 'Save' : 'Update'; ?>"> 
                                                                <?php if (empty($s_state[0]) || empty($s_state)): ?> 
                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btnsix" data-target="#collapse6" data-toggle="collapse">Save</button> 
                                                                <?php else: ?> 
                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btnsix" data-target="#collapse6" data-toggle="collapse">Update</button> 
                                                                <?php endif; ?> 
                                                                <button type="button" data-target="#collapse6" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button> 
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--6 pannel ends-->
```

**ajax call**

```
$(".aj-textfive").html(result.replace_textfive); $(".aj-text-btnfive").html(result.btn_textfive); $("#save_country").val(result.save_country); $('#ccountry').text($("#country").val());
```

---

```
 $(".aj-textsix").html(result.replace_textsix);
 $(".aj-text-btnsix").html(result.btn_textsix);

 $("#save_state").val(result.save_state);
 $('#cstate').text($("#state").val());
```

---

Comment: format the code please. Don't copy and Paste entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just replace below code**

```
<select name="state" id="state" type ="text" class="form-control"  
            value="<?= (isset($s_state)) ? $s_state : null; ?>"><br> 
        <option value="<?php echo $s_state; ?>">--select--</option>
        <option value="indiaa">indiaa</option>
        <option value="aussss">aussss</option>
    </select>
```